# Branch.io Deep linking not working on iOS 13+. It does not show pop-up to open application(Ionic 5, Capacitor)

Tags: branch.io, capacitor, ionic5, capacitor-plugin

I have added deep-linking integration in our app and using plugin [capacitor-branch-deep-links](https://www.npmjs.com/package/capacitor-branch-deep-links). It is working till iOS 12.1 but in iOS 13+ it does not show a pop-up to open the application on a click of deep-link.

I have also tried forced uri redirect mode but none of these solutions are working.
https://help.branch.io/using-branch/docs/creating-a-deep-link#forced-redirections

```
Installed Dependencies:
Ionic 5.26.0
@capacitor/cli 2.4.5
@capacitor/core 2.4.5
@capacitor/ios 2.4.5
capacitor-branch-deep-links 3.0.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through [this](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/react-native-branch-deep-linking-attribution/issues/158) link, I figured out that I was using the wrong `Apple App Prefix` and invalid `Provisioning Profile Specifier`. This correction fixed my issue. Though I am still not sure why it was working in iOS 12 with the wrong Apple App Prefix and Provision Profile

Comment: Can you share the Quick link which you are using? By your description, it seems that the application is launched through URI schemes.

Comment: @KartikShandilya You can check out this link.
https://ssw.app.link/6yFJHUdwzbb